# How to merge objects having same/common field?

Tags: java, sorting, dictionary, merge

i have a requirement in which i will retrieve all the records from the DB in a sorted form. These records will be sorted by "EnteredIds" field in DB.I am getting these records perfectly. I am placing these records in Map. So certainly I will have my map like :

```
<field1, EnteredId1> 
<field4, EnteredId1> 
<field3, EnteredId1> 
<field2, EnteredId1> 
<field6, EnteredId2> 
<field1, EnteredId2> 
<field2, EnteredId2>
```

where `EnteredId` is in sorted form (i.e 1,1,1,1,2,2,2,...).
Now I want another list which will have objects according to the `EnteredIds` Like

```
Object1 will contain 4 records having EnteredId = EnteredId1.
Object2 will contain 3 records having EnteredId = EnteredId2.
```

and so on..
I have tried it using Map but the logic seems to be very much time consuming and very less optimized.

Please help..
Thanks in advance..

Comment: I don't quite get your example: you say you're using maps but you also seem to have multiple identical keys. This won't work with a normal map. Do you mean `MultiMap` instead?

Comment: You also say that the map would be sorted on `EnteredId`, which is the map value. The only standard map I know that would allow you to do something similar would be a `LinkedHashMap` which would order the entries by insertion order and thus the values would have to be sorted already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I still don't fully understand your question, I'll try an attempt to answer it.

I assume you have a map like this:

```
field1->id1
field2->id1
field3->id1
field4->id2
...
```

I further assume you want to get it the other way round, i.e.

```
id1 -> field1, field2, field3
id2 -> field4
...
```

This could be achieved by using a `Map<Id,List<Field>>` or better a `MultiMap` which [Google Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) or [Apache Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html) provide.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer? Means in `Map<Id,List<Field>>` what is Id and field considering my example ?

Comment: @adn_295 It was just me bein lazy: `Id = EnteredId` and `Field` is the type of the keys in your example (i.e. `field1`, `field2` etc.)

Comment: OK. But how can I get those `EnteredIds` in a distinct way ? means from `map<field, EnteredId>`, how to get unique `EnteredIds`? as they are multiple records having same `EnteredIds` as shown in example.

Comment: @adn_295 As I tried to point out: use the reverse mapping. Map keys are normally distinct, hence the mapping from `EnteredId` to a list of fields. To make life easier, use a `MulitMap` for that.

Comment: I resolved the issue using another way i.e directly firing query in such a way that I will get desired o/p. However thanks for help..

Answer (score 0):

Is it required to keep the elements in a sorted manner? Else you could use a `LinkedHashMap`, which simply is a hashmap, which put elements with the same key in a linked list. So if you add 3 elements with enteredId1 (as key), they will be stored in a linked list at the same index of the map, which will allow O(1) access to the key. This will be very fast unless you will be storing alot of elements with the same key. You can read a bit more about it [here:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. i will surely check the same.